# How to close a java frame that was automatically created

Tags: java, frame

I used the NteBeans' GUI making tool.
It created a frame.
I want to close this frame using a button.
I know that I need to use "my_frame_name.dispose();" to close a frame.
But the problem is I cant find the name of the frame in the "Source" tab.
I think this is because, NetBeans created this frame and its code automatically.

Could anyone tell me how to close this frame using a code or a function, please?

Please don't tell me I have to recode everything, because I have multiple frames like tis one and don't have the luxury of time.

Comment: Do you have any code to show of how the frame opens or anything that could help us find what this frame is named?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one also

Here program is using `container.getParent()` method to find out the top most `JFrame`.

```
public static void main(String[] a) {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();

    JPanel p = new JPanel();
    final JButton btn = new JButton("close");
    btn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            Container parent = btn;
            while ((parent = parent.getParent()) != null) {
                System.out.println(parent.getClass().getName());
                if (parent instanceof JFrame) {
                    ((JFrame) parent).setVisible(false);
                } else {
                    parent = parent.getParent();
                }
            }
        }
    });
    p.add(btn);

    frame.getContentPane().add(p);

    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
}
```